# Filtering DataFrame rows which have overlapping values cross-columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that reflects rows with at least one `id` conflict inside that row.

```
      email id1 id2 id3
0      de@l  Z7  Q4  Q4
1     sco@g  Q4  Z7  Q4
2   alpha@n  Q4  Z7  Z7
3   numer@o  Z7  Z7  Q4
4    endo@c  D8  D8  L1
5  chrono@k  L1  L1  D8
```

Rows 0-3 and rows 4-5 have overlapping `id` values with other rows, but the overlap occurs across various columns.

How can I:

1. drop all but the **first row** of each overlap group,
2. in a table-wise or series-wise manner, ie **without using `df.apply()` down the rows**

This would be the output (though don't care about index):

```
      email id1 id2 id3
0      de@l  Z7  Q4  Q4
4    endo@c  D8  D8  L1
```

---

Below snippet for easy repro

```
pd.DataFrame([
    {'email':'de@l', 'id1':'Z7', 'id2':'Q4', 'id3':'Q4'},
    {'email':'sco@g', 'id1':'Q4', 'id2':'Z7', 'id3':'Q4'},
    {'email':'alpha@n', 'id1':'Q4', 'id2':'Z7', 'id3':'Z7'},
    {'email':'numer@o', 'id1':'Z7', 'id2':'Z7', 'id3':'Q4'},
    {'email':'endo@c', 'id1':'D8', 'id2':'D8', 'id3':'L1'},
    {'email':'chrono@k','id1':'L1', 'id2':'L1', 'id3':'D8'},
])
```

Comment: What do you think `ie without using df.apply() down the rows` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is convert columns with `id` values to hashable sets called frozensets, so possible filter by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with inverted mask in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df.filter(like='id').apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
#for test all columns without first
#df = df[~df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
print (df)
    email id1 id2 id3
0    de@l  Z7  Q4  Q4
4  endo@c  D8  D8  L1
```

Alternative with list comprehension:

```
L = [frozenset(x) for x in df.filter(like='id').to_numpy()]
df = df[~pd.Series(L, index=df.index).duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) with [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), then we create a boolean index.

```
arr = df.filter(like='id').to_numpy().astype(str)
arr = np.apply_along_axis(np.unique, 1, arr)
m = (arr[1:]!=arr[:-1]).all(axis=1)
m = np.r_[False, m]

df[m]

    email id1 id2 id3
0    de@l  Z7  Q4  Q4
4  endo@c  D8  D8  L1
```